# Avoiding a Point(LatLng) while drawing poly line in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am getting Latitude and Longitude values from webservice and i am storing them in arraylist. From the arraylist i need to draw polylines with those values with some condition. The condition is if the difference between the two lat,long values is more than one metre. i need to avoid that particular lat,long value which is very far away. i have used the following code snippet.

**Snippet:**

```
    private void redrawLine()
    {

    mMap.clear();  //clears all Markers and Polylines

    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < coordList.size(); i++) {
    point = coordList.get(i);
      }
    for(int j=1; j<coordList.size();j++){
        points = coordList.get(j);
    }
    CalculationByDistance(point,points);
    int m = meterInDec*1000;
    if(m>1){
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, String.valueOf(m), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   //do nothing
    }
    else{
        options.add(point);   //add points
    }
   // addMarker(); //add Marker in current position
    line = mMap.addPolyline(options); //add Polyline
}
```

**Method CalculationByDistance**

```
    public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
    int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
    double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
    double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
    double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
    double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double valueResult = Radius * c;
    double km = valueResult / 1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    double meter = valueResult % 1000;
    meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
    Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
            + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

    return Radius * c;
}
```

When use these conditions. i am unable to draw lines. but if there is no condition, it works fine.

Comment: CalculationByDistance(point,points); is outside the for loop. you cannot draw a polygon with single point.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign values to the point and points variables only the last record from the coordList will get assigned to them. The calculations that you will be doing will be based on only the last record.

```
for (int i = 0; i < coordList.size(); i++) {
    point = coordList.get(i);
}
for(int j=1; j<coordList.size();j++){
    points = coordList.get(j);
}
CalculationByDistance(point,points);
```

You will either need to either move the distance calculation inside the loop or change the logic of redrawLine method

Comment: i tried something like this.
       `for (int i = 0; i < coordList.size(); i++) {
       point = coordList.get(i);
       points = coordList.get(i+1);
       CalculationByDistance(point,points);
`}`
But still unable to draw lines. @joyson